# How to mock static and non static methods in the same class using Powermockito

Tags: junit, powermockito

I have a class which has both static and non static methods and would like to write unit test cases for the same.
    ClassA{

```
static getInstance()
{
   // to do logic
}

void log()
{
  system.out.print();
}
}
```

And the test case for classA is

```
ClassTest
{
  public void setup()
{
       PowerMockito.mockStatic(ClassA.class);
        mockA = PowerMockito.mock(ClassA.class);

      Mockito.when(ClassA.getInstance("user")).thenReturn(mockA);
        Mockito.doNothing().when(mockA).log(Mockito.anyString(),  Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(Exception.class), Mockito.anyMap());

    enter code here

}
}
```

When i call log method, i am getting exception. How do we mock this?

Answer (score 1):

Serious answer: **don't do that**.

Simply avoid writing production code that requires PowerMock; for example because you are mixing in calls to static methods.

Typically, a "need for PowerMock" directly translates to: your design needs to be improved!

You will find pretty quickly that PowerMock creates more problems that it is solving. Thus: avoid using it.

Comment: Also, I would suggest that if you write production code first and then try to get a test around it, you're doing it in exactly the wrong order. Try writing the tests first and see if you can't get the hang of that--it will cause your production code to become more simple, clear and easy to test.